How can I use the .astype() method to change the dtype of two columns within a dataframe?
q7 = {
    0: [4, 5.0, 2.0, 9.0, 1.0, 8],
    1: [5, 6.0, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan, 2],
    2: [6, np.nan, 7.0, np.nan, 4.0, 3]}

q7 = q7[0].astype(int)
q7 = q7[5].astype(int)
Q7 = pd.DataFrame(q7).T
Q7.fillna(100, inplace=True)
Q7

I have tried
q7 = q7[0].astype(int)
q7 = q7[5].astype(int)

However, I expect the following.
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   4   5.0 2.0 9.0 1.0 8
1   5   6.0 NaN 3.0 NaN 2
2   6   NaN 7.0 NaN 4.0 3

The first column are the titles

Your code is a little confusing because q7 is not a dataframe while Q7 is. It's not clear why you want to call as type on a python list. If you start with a dataframe like Q7 = pd.DataFrame(q7).T, then  Q7[0] = Q7[0].astype(int) might give you what you want.

In this code, q7[0] is a list, which doesn't have an .astype() method, and q7[5] doesn't exist. Did you make some typos or something? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] if you want more tips. And if it's any help, How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

Is this what you're looking for? ntg's answer on "Convert Python dict into a dataframe"

You must first create the dataframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

q7 = {
    0: [4, 5.0, 2.0, 9.0, 1.0, 8],
    1: [5, 6.0, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan, 2],
    2: [6, np.nan, 7.0, np.nan, 4.0, 3]}


Q7 = pd.DataFrame(q7).T


Q7[0] = Q7[0].astype(int)  

Q7[5] = Q7[5].astype(int) 

print(Q7)

which gives
   0    1    2    3    4  5
0  4  5.0  2.0  9.0  1.0  8
1  5  6.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  2
2  6  NaN  7.0  NaN  4.0  3

